# Post method always return null MVC4

Tags: .net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, post, razor

My controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public void setInfoUser(string str)
        {
            Demandeur demandeur = new Demandeur(str);
        }
```

My view :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("setInfoUser", "Personne", FormMethod.Post))
    {
       <input type="text" id="idUser" value="test" />
       <input type="submit" value="ok" name="setInfoUser" />
   }
```

The method is fired but the string is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not binding anything to that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set name attribute to be equal to your string variable.

```
 <input type="text" id="idUser" name="str" value="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use model based approach since you are using mvc 

**View:**

```
@model Your_NameSpace.Demandeur 
@using (Html.BeginForm("setInfoUser", "Personne", FormMethod.Post))
 {
  @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.UserName)
  <input type="submit" value="ok" name="setInfoUser" />
 }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void setInfoUser(Demandeur demandeur)
 {
   //your logic ahead
 }
```